# How to return multiple JSON objects using Spark SQL in Scala

Tags: sql, json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file and a json file. Within count.csv there are three columns (latitude, longitude, count). Within the json, here is an example:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
  "ID": "15280000000231",
  "TYPES": "Second Class",
  "N2C": "9",
  "NAME": "Century Road"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        6.1395489,
        52.3107973
      ],
      [
        6.1401178,
        52.3088457
      ],
      [
        6.1401126,
        52.3088071
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently my scala code approximates and matches the longitude and latitude and filters the csv file for matching lon/lat, returning the lat/lon and count as a csv.

I would like to return all the properties (ID, TYPE, N2C and NAME) from the json, and return the matching lat/lon as the original linestring + count from csv + properties from json all as a json file instead of csv.

So far I've been struggling to do this?

```
case class ScoredLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, score: Int)

object ScoreFilter {
  val Epsilon = 10000

  val DoubleToRoundInt = udf(
    (coord:Double) => (coord * Epsilon).toInt
  )

  val schema = Encoders.product[ScoredLocation].schema
  val route_count = spark.read.schema(schema).format("csv").load("count.csv")
    .withColumn("lat_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt($"latitude"))
    .withColumn("lon_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt($"longitude"))

  val match_route = spark.read.format("json").load("matchroute.json")
    .select(explode($"geometry.coordinates"))
    .select($"col".getItem(0).alias("latitude"), $"col".getItem(1).alias("longitude"))
    .withColumn("lat_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt($"latitude"))
    .withColumn("lon_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt($"longitude"))

  europe_count.show()
  scenic_route.show()

  val result = route_count.join(match_route, Seq("lat_aprx", "lon_aprx"), "leftsemi")
    .select($"latitude", $"longitude", $"count")

  result.show()
  result.write.format("csv").save("result.csv")
}
```

Response edit:

I get this error using the solution.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`ID`' given input columns: [count, latitude, 
longitude, lat_aprx, lon_aprx];;
'Project [latitude#3, longitude#4, score#5, 'ID, 'TYPES, 'N2C, 'NAME]
+- Project [lat_aprx#10, lon_aprx#16, latitude#3, longitude#4,score#5]
  +- Join LeftSemi, ((lat_aprx#10 = lat_aprx#55) && (lon_aprx#16 = lon_aprx#63))
     :- Project [latitude#3, longitude#4, score#5, lat_aprx#10, if 
(isnull(longitude#4)) null else UDF(longitude#4) AS lon_aprx#16]
      :  +- Project [latitude#3, longitude#4, count#5, if 
(isnull(latitude#3)) null else UDF(latitude#3) AS lat_aprx#10]
      :     +- Relation[latitude#3,longitude#4,count#5] csv
      +- Project [ID#38, TYPES#39, N2C#40, NAME#41, coords#48, 
lat_aprx#55, if (isnull(coords#48[1])) null else UDF(coords#48[1]) AS 
lon_aprx#63]
         +- Project [ID#38, TYPES#39, N2C#40, NAME#41, coords#48, if 
 (isnull(coords#48[0])) null else UDF(coords#48[0]) AS lat_aprx#55]
             +- Project [properties#32.ID AS ID#38, 
properties#32.TYPES AS TYPES#39, properties#32.N2C AS N2C#40, 
properties#32.NAME AS NAME#41, coords#48]
                +- Generate explode(geometry#31.coordinates), true, 
 false, [coords#48]
                  +- Relation[geometry#31,properties#32,type#33] json
```

Edit 2: I'm now returning json with the count added, but the problem now is to return as the original geojson, as type linestring, with the count added up, example below. It should be more like the original json above. I suppose it can be manipulated after, but I was hoping to do this as one spark sql process. Any ideas?

```
{  
   "lat":5.2509524,
   "lon":53.3926721,
   "count":1,
   "ID":"15280000814947",
   "TYPES":"Second Class",
   "N2C":"9"
}{  
   "lat":5.251464,
   "lon":53.3919782,
   "count":4,
   "ID":"15280000814947",
   "TYPES":"Second Class",
   "N2C":"9"
}{  
   "lat":5.251674,
   "lon":53.3916119,
   "count":4,
   "ID":"15280000814947",
   "TYPES":"Second Class",
   "N2C":"9"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you process the `match_route` dataframe, make sure to select all the columns you actually want to keep. For example:

```
val match_route = spark.read.format("json").load("matchroute.json")
  .select($"properties.*", explode($"geometry.coordinates").as("coords"))
  .withColumn("latitude", $"coords".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("longitude", $"coords".getItem(1))
  .withColumn("lat_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt(latitude))
  .withColumn("lon_aprx", DoubleToRoundInt(longitude))
  .drop($"coords")
```

Make sure to add the relevant columns in the last select as well,

```
val result = route_count.join(match_route, Seq("lat_aprx", "lon_aprx"), "leftsemi")
  .select($"latitude", $"longitude", $"count", $"ID", $"TYPES", $"N2C", $"NAME")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to properly add an edit response, I run into an error on the join and last select now. I added it above on my original post. 

Secondly, the lat/lon returned with this won't be the original linestring?

Comment: @WhaleSaver I updated the answer, it's looks a bit better now. Yes, I had missed that it was the `latitude` and `longitude` columns that were selected in the end, added them to the dataframe.

Comment: It ended up being the leftsemi that was the problem, but I've fixed that with an inner join. I edited the original to show what it's now returning. Ideally I'd like linestring geojson, any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: @WhaleSaver: I'm not familiar with linestring geojson but I think it should be possible. I would suggest opening a new question regarding it since it looks like it would make a good separate question.